# Recurrent issue Integrated webcam is used by another application

Tags: windows-10, drivers, symbolic-link, webcam, process-explorer

I am having issue with my webcam it stops working randomly for indefinite time, these issue first occurred to me year ago after that I have reinstalled windows one time but these issue comes up occasionally.

Things I did,

- Applications have proper access to webcam meaning proper privacy settings Windows 10.
- Disabling/Uninstalling device doesn't work.
- I used `procexp.exe` of sys internals to search for `Physical Device Object Name`, `Driver Files` but doesn't get any results in search
- I followed steps in [this](https://webcamtests.com/help/your-webcam-is-used-by-another-application-on-windows) article using `procexp.exe` to search for `#vid` but only results came up are of type `Symbolic Link` having handle name similar to `Device Instance Path` and have prefix like this
  `\GLOBAL??\USB#VID_` and all of them are under `System` process.

Questions:

- Is it normal to have Symbolic link attached to Device handle?
- What is blocking my webcam?
- Does symbolic links I found in search are malicious?

Answer (score 0):

The issue webcam is used by another application or it is blocked may be due to various reasons. It may be blocked for the app you are using. Go to the privacy panel in the control panel settings > camera privacy and check for the app if it is allowed or not to access the camera.

Comment: I already did that and these problem isn't consistent it reoccurs in random intervals. I generally use webcam on browser it works most the time but these issue pops up ones in while and resolves on it's own after some days or weeks.